# javascript and email

Tags: javascript, email, window.open

I get it to send an email using javascript I use window.open('mailto:xxx') What I would like to avoid is opening a new browser window + opening an email window. Works fine except for that. I do my programming in CF. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "window.open()"

Either use an `<a href="mailto:XXX"></a>` in your HTML,
or use `location.href="mailto:XXX";` if it needs to be Javascript.

Comment: `location.href` is not a function; trying to invoke it will throw a `TypeError`.

Comment: <a href="mailto:...  won't work in this instance because I'm using a cloaking scheme so actual email addresses don't appear in the HTML. Clicking the apparent email address invokes a javascript function to decode the coded email address and, at the end of the function, actually pop open the users email window with the address in the To: position (i.e., emulating mailto:)

Comment: @user1329944 , does the JS solution suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

`location.href="mailto://xxx";`

Comment: `href` is not a function -- your first revision was correct.  Better is to use `location.assign()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`location.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location):

```
location.assign('mailto:user@example.com');
```

While you can instead directly assign to `location`'s properties (`location.href='mailto:...';`) to cause the browser to navigate, I recommend against this.

Internally, doing so is just calling `location.assign()` anyway, and assigning to properties does not always behave the same in all browsers.